# How can I track metrics on who does code reviews in JIRA?

Tags: workflow, jira, jira-agile

I'm working on a project that's got a great JIRA setup and awesome buy-in of everyone for the agile development process. The issue I'm having is that tickets stack up in code review. I'd like to be able to see who code reviewed what, much like I can see who has closed out which tickets.

I know that metrics are there to be used for good and not evil, so I want to do this to ensure that people spending time code reviewing are properly credited instead of that time not being recognized at all.

Currently, everyone who does code review assigns themselves to the ticket (which is unassigned upon being placed into the "Ready for Review" workflow state), so at some point there is a record of them working on it. Is this a good way to track the reviewers and is there a way to get aggregate information this after the fact? If not, is there a better way of representing this information in JIRA?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution would be to add a custom field called 'Code Reviewer' of type select a user. You would be able to search on that and report on it.

You could workflow it so that when the issue is transitioned out of your 'Code Review' status a window pops up containing only the "Code Reviewer' custom field to be completed.

What you need to do:

1. Create a new custom field - this is done in the 'Issues' configuration menu. Ensure your custom field uses the 'select a user' type.
   https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Adding+a+Custom+Field
2. Create a new Screen - this is also done in the 'Issues configuration menu. On your new screen you need to make sure that the only field that is visible is your new custom field.
   https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Defining+a+Screen
3. Edit your workflow. Find the transition from out of 'Code Review' and associate it with your custom screen.
   https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Configuring+Workflow

The result will be that when a user transitions out of 'Code Review' they will have the custom screen pop-up. They can then select the name of the person who did the code review and this will be populated in the custom field.

Comment: That sounds like a great start! I will figure out how to do those steps as you outlined, and I'll come back and accept your answer. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I don't know if I can edit comments. Does this solution require me to add a third party plugin? That's what I read here: https://confluence.atlassian.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=310378700 I may not have access to be able to do this.

Comment: There is no need for a third-party plugin. You use a new screen to update the custom field, rather than changing the field automatically in the transition. I have updated my answer to give more detail.

Comment: Hmm, so the "In Code Review" state of the Workflow automatically assigns the user to the ticket when they transition into it, so they're already temporarily assigned to the ticket and tracked there. Maybe the transition could increment a counter of the custom field with the current user? So I could track how many Code Reviews that user has successfully conducted?

Comment: It is possible, but I think you will need to write a script to do it. That is outside of my area of expertise I'm afraid. It may be worth posting a new question.

Comment: Alright, thanks! Technically you did answer my question as I posted it, so I will accept it. I appreciate the help!